# SQlite3 bound params and LIKE

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

Sqlite3 provides the `sqlite3_bind_*` functions which allow one to do parameter substitution into a SQL query.  My question is: what is the right way to combine this with LIKE queries?  For example, I might want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM thing WHERE name LIKE '%?'
```

but that doesn't work at all.  Is the best way really just:

```
SELECT * FROM thing WHERE name LIKE ?
```

and then put the pattern characters into the actual string value to be substituted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate strings, use the `||` operator:

```sql
SELECT * FROM thing WHERE name LIKE '%' || ?
```